# How can I use a number as a column name in SQL?

Tags: sql

I want to create a column name like 0-60MPH in a table.How is it possible?
Thanks for the reply.

Comment: for mySQL : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html

Comment: Don't.  Call it `mph_0_60` or something like that.  There is no reason to start a column name with a non-standard character.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can quote the column name:

```
 "0-60MPH"   -- SQL Standard
 `0-60MPH`   -- MySQL/MariaDB
 [0-60MPH]   -- SQL Server
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/391827)**</kbd> <kbd>**[`SqlFiddleMySQL`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/583da/1/0)**</kbd>

But I suggest to rename column and use `_` like `from_0_to_60_mph`. Quoting identifiers in long run causes more problems than benefits.